# Can't register conditional snippet

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to register some functions to autocomplete. To raw function text it works as well, however, I can't assign it to conditional snippet functions.

```
        //Register the custom completion function into Monaco Editor
        monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(lang, {
            provideCompletionItems: function(model, position, context, token) {
                return [
                    {
                        label: 'sop',
                        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
                        documentation: "Show a debug message on console terminal",
                        insertText: 'show_debug_message();'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'ifelse',
                        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Snippet,
                        insertText: [
                            'if ${1:condition} {',
                            '\t$0',
                            '} else {',
                            '\t',
                            '}'
                        ].join('\n'),
                        insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet,
                        documentation: 'If-Else Statement'
                    }
                ];
            }
        });
```

The following code: `insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet,` is not found, raising this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'InsertAsSnippet' of undefined`. Rather that even I specify 4 for "insertTextRules" attribute nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not running a stripped down version of monaco? I've checked but there's nothing wrong with your code as far as I can tell, I copied the code below out of a working piece of my own code.

`insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet`